# VPD access failed after software update

Tags: linux, fedora, boot

I'm running Fedora 36 beta on a Thinkpad T14 (gen 1). I ran my regular software updates and went to restart the machine to finish the process. Unfortunately this failed.

Right now I'm getting a grub error (I turned off quiet on boot):

```
r8169 0000:02:00.0: invalid VPD tag 0x00 (size 0 at offset 0); assume missing optional EEPROM
serial 0000:02:00.1: VPD access failed. This is likely a firmware bug on this device. Contact the card vendor for a firmware update.
serial 0000:02:00.2: VPD access failed. This is likely a firmware bug on this device. Contact the card vendor for a firmware update.
pci 0000:02:00.3: VPD access failed. This is likely a firmware bug on this device. Contact the card vendor for a firmware update.
ehci-pci 0000:02:00.4: VPD access failed. This is likely a firmware bug on this device. Contact the card vendor for a firmware update.
```

Obviously I am capable of reading the error message. I have no idea what part this is referring to, nor how to load a firmware update, nor how I would get this onto the computer.

Are there any commands I can run that would let me boot into anything, even a basic terminal? I am able to get to the grub console, but that's something I'm not familiar with.

Any ideas? Happy to provide more information as necessary.

Comment: Just to state this, while I'm happy to provide additional info, I'm headed to bed right now so it'll be a little bit before I can respond. Also, I _do_ have a Fedora 36 live disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That message does not come from GRUB, but from the PCI bus driver code of the Linux kernel: see https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/drivers/pci/vpd.c?h=v5.17.2#n151

The fact that you can see the message indicates GRUB has already done its job and gone away: the Linux kernel has successfully started up and is in the process of detecting hardware on the system PCI(e) bus.

VPD means Vital Product Data and it provides basic PCI(e) bus configuration information.

Try selecting the previous kernel version from the GRUB boot menu, or boot from your live disk. If it works just as before the update, then the newest updates brought in a kernel that seems to have a bug in it. Since Fedora 36 is still in beta phase, I would suggest sending in a bug report.

If the previous kernel version and live disk also keep failing the same way, it is possible your laptop just happened to develop a hardware fault.

Or if you experimented with low-level hardware tools, you may have accidentally corrupted something vital to the system's functioning: in particular, the utilities of the `i2c-tools` package have been known to cause malfunctions in some Thinkpads. Although the current versions of those tools default to avoiding operations that are known to cause problems, it's still possible to override the safety checks if you think you know better... and the tool developers cannot possibly test with every PC model in the world.

For example, the documentation of the `eepromer` utility of the `i2c-tools` package includes the following:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Warning !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!                                                                           !
!!! This program should only be used on external busses such as i2c-pport.    !
!!!                                                                           !
!!! Your computer may contain i2c-eeproms for saving data vital to its       !
!!! operation. If you are not careful you might overwrite this data with      !
!!! this program and your computer may no longer boot!                        !
!!!                                                                           !
!!! An example are the EEPROMS on your SDRAM DIMMs, your computer may no      !
!!! longer detect the RAM module rendering it essentially USELESS!            !
!!!                                                                           !
!!! IBM Thinkpads are said to store their configuration data in a eeprom,     !
!!! if you manage to overwrite this eeprom you will have to send your         !
!!! computer to the manufacturer for a costly repair!                         !
!!!                                                                           !
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Warning !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! I have not manually changed anything in the kernel. Fedora 36 has the 5.17.1 kernel. I just tried the next 3 on the list (two regular kernels and one recovery) and all failed. The regular kernels all with the same reason, while the recovery kernel boots into "emergency mode". However, I can't do anything there because the root account is locked. I am able to boot to the live disk that I have — this is from an earlier beta iso.

Comment: So on the plus side it's not a hardware issue. How can I use the live disk to run `sudo dnf update` on the installed system? Or even just rolling back the kernel or skipping this part if it wouldn't break anything else. At this point I'm basically open to whatever works.

Comment: Alright. I got `dnf upgrade` to work via `chroot`. Unfortunately that didn't help. So the live disk works and even the old kernels do not. I did just verify that the hardware is fine: I plugged in an ethernet cord and it works as expected.

Comment: OK, so it's not a *fatal* hardware/firmware issue. The error messages might be just an unrelated nuisance. You might want to use the chroot with the live disk to set a password for the root account, which would allow the emergency mode to be used, then continue troubleshooting from there. If the emergency mode works, this sounds like a possible GPU driver problem. By the way, have you tried pressing Ctrl-Alt-F1 (possibly with Fn) in normal mode? If the kernel is still alive, and the GPU state is not too messed up, it should give you a text console with a login prompt.

Comment: Emergency mode works with a root password set. So now I can run whatever without the live disk. Ctrl-Alt-F2 (it looks like F1 is the default nowadays) does **not** work. It gives a black screen with a cursor. So it looks like it's the GPU and the other error was misleading/superfluous? Just to restate this, I'm on a Thinkpad T14 gen 1. Ryzen 4750U, no dedicated GPU.

Comment: Did a little digging and tried to boot into single-user mode. It fails to start `dbus-broker.service`, with `systemctl status dbis-broker.service` indicating an exit with code -13, tracing back to `launcher_run@../src/launch/launcher.c +1340`.

Comment: Scratch that location. It tries to add a file watcher and it gets a "permission denied" error. It originates at [this line](https://github.com/bus1/dbus-broker/blob/727bee57cd3e3b5806eb8599abbdd49984b75732/src/util/dirwatch.c#L122). journalctl shows the first instance of this error is a couple days ago, which is when this first started happening. I think we've found the source, even if indirect!

Comment: That error led me to the fix! As it turns out, that error has been encountered before on previous Fedora releases. **Disabling selinux is what's necessary.** I did that and it booted right up! I'm going to go ahead and accept this answer, even if it was nowhere near straightforward. Because you lead me in the right direction :) Thank you for your time! It really is appreciated.